# JSP form nested checkboxes

Tags: spring, jsp

A project was passed onto me a short while ago which uses JSP for the view and spring 3.1 for the controller - both of which I have little experience in and as per usual, there are about 4 comments in the whole thing. Anyway, my issue is this, in replacing a

```
<form:checkboxes path="class.list" items="${items}" delimiter="<br />" />
```

With

```
<c:forEach var="item" varStatus="vs" items="${items}">
    <form:checkbox path="class.list" item="${item}" />
    // check if nesting is required, if so create div and nested list point to class.list.children
</c:forEach>
```

Seems to create additional elements in my class.list which are not selected leading to a break further on.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: the list that the checkboxes points to have additional instances which were not selected from the checkboxes, thus leading to a break further on.

I've noticed that using form:checkboxes renders a singular hidden input field where as the forEach renders one for each checkbox, I assume this will have some negative affect..?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest leaving the form:checkboxes intact as it is a compact way to generate checkboxes. I do not know of a compelling reason not to use the spring form tags if it is already in place and working. As to why you are seeing hidden fields. See here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html

Here is the relevant portion:
What you might not expect to see is the additional hidden field after each checkbox. When a checkbox in an HTML page is not checked, its value will not be sent to the server as part of the HTTP request parameters once the form is submitted, so we need a workaround for this quirk in HTML in order for Spring form data binding to work. The checkbox tag follows the existing Spring convention of including a hidden parameter prefixed by an underscore ("_") for each checkbox. By doing this, you are effectively telling Spring that “ the checkbox was visible in the form and I want my object to which the form data will be bound to reflect the state of the checkbox no matter what ”.

Hope this helps.